# Fprintf with Servefile

Tags: csv, http, go

```
func examp(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request){
    text:="hi"
    fmt.Fprintf(w,"%d \n",text)

    http.ServeFile(w, req, "./sample.csv")
}
```

I can not use http.servefile with fmt.Fprintf, always use first one. I was tryed w.Header().add but nothing changed. How can i fix it ?

Comment: There is no fix fir this. You can serve a file with ServeFile in which case exactly that file is served and noting else or you can write our own response body e.g. via Fprintf in which case you cannot use Serve file. Dead simple. If you want to prefix the file content with some data you must implement this on your own.

Comment: As @Volker said: you can't mix `ServeFile()` and manual content writing. `ServeFile()` takes care of headers (e.g. `content-type`) which is not possible if you write some content prior (as that implicitly writes the headers).

Answer (score 0):

`http.ServeFile` adds `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` and writes the header. This must happen before you write to `http.ResponseWriter`.

Your solution could be to avoid `http.ServeFile` and write the file manually with `io.Copy`:

```golang
func example(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // Write some headers.
    w.Header.Set("Content-Type", mime.TypeByExtension(filepath.Ext(name)))

    // Write your content here.
    fmt.Fprint(w, someContent)

    // Write the file.
    fileName := "sample.csv"
    f, err := io.Open(fileName)
    // check err
    _, err = io.Copy(w, f)
    // check err
}
```

The downside of `io.Copy` is that it doesn't support Range requests (for resuming downloads, etc.)

Comment: This makes Content-Length incorrect. Either add the length of the string written before the file or omit it.

Comment: @Peter You're correct. I think for the sake of simplicity, I'll just omit it.

Comment: 1) I can not see "Open" func in https://golang.org/pkg/io/

2) w.Header.Set("... must be  ->  "w.Header().Set("...

I am not sure this comment. I want see value of csv in browser page and automated download (its mean ->If this endpoint is entered in the browser, write the data and download it directly<-